# faster method of testing uwsgi + nginx

Tags: integration-tests, sockets, http-request

Im currently looking for a way to test a lot of requests in the shortest amount of time possible on my web application.  My current workaround is to just import the modules I want to test into another python file and shoot requests directly into those functions, but I'd rather have it go through the web server framework as it normally does when live.  My issue with that is going through all of these requests using HTTP protocol takes too long for my liking.

I'm using uwsgi behind nginx, is there any way to just put a request directly through a socket for nginx?  Or are there any other methods that could work and still be relatively quick when processing a lot of test requests?

Comment: Isn't testing an HTTP application with... HTTP ...kinda the whole point?

Comment: yes but there are a lot of combinations of requests I'm trying to test and it would be quicker to bypass the HTTP portion and just make sure all of the logic for the functions are correct when working together.  Maybe I'm going about this the wrong way though?